# HazelCast and DB2 integration using MapStore

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am trying to load the data from DB2 to HazelCast using MapStore ( and MapLoader) by executing the Stored Procedure. I am able to retrieve the Data from DB2, but when it try to load the data into HazelCast, I am getting the following exception

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: MapLoader loaded an item belongs to a
>   different partition   at
>   com.hazelcast.util.executor.CompletableFutureTask.run(CompletableFutureTask.java:69)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.util.executor.CachedExecutorServiceDelegate$Worker.run(CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:227)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:64)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:80)
>   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: MapLoader loaded an item belongs to a
>   different partition   at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(InvocationFuture.java:92)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:162)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.BasicRecordStoreLoader.loadValuesInternal(BasicRecordStoreLoader.java:141)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.BasicRecordStoreLoader.access$100(BasicRecordStoreLoader.java:52)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.BasicRecordStoreLoader$GivenKeysLoaderTask.call(BasicRecordStoreLoader.java:109)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.util.executor.CompletableFutureTask.run(CompletableFutureTask.java:67)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: MapLoader
>   loaded an item belongs to a different partition   at
>   com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.DefaultRecordStore.isKeyAndValueLoadable(DefaultRecordStore.java:1031)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.DefaultRecordStore.putFromLoadInternal(DefaultRecordStore.java:987)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.DefaultRecordStore.putFromLoad(DefaultRecordStore.java:978)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.PutFromLoadAllOperation.run(PutFromLoadAllOperation.java:74)
>     at com.hazelcast.spi.Operation.call(Operation.java:148)     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.call(OperationRunnerImpl.java:202)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:191)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:120)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:100)
>     at ------ submitted from ------.(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolve(InvocationFuture.java:127)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(InvocationFuture.java:79)
>     ... 11 more

If anyone did HazelCast and DB2 integration with MapStore by executing "Stored Procedure".

Thanks,
Ram

Comment: Do you transform item key before returning it in you implementation of findAllById(Collection<K> keys) ?

Answer (score 3):

@katteriamma, problem is `PutFromLoadAllOperation` operation. Signature of `loadAll` method is `Map<K,V> loadAll(Collection<K> keys)`.

What is happening in your case is your `loadAll` methods returns extra key-value pairs which don't belong to the caller partition. You need to make sure that you only return key-value map for `Collection<K> keys`, nothing more. `loadAll` method will be invoked for each partition anyway. So you need to make sure that your stored procedure only return data for given keys or you need to filter the extra key-value pairs.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue like yours. In my case, loadAllKeys() returned a set of keys, using those keys the loadAll() method loaded the data into the map from the datastore. The loadAll() method manipulated the original keys when loading data into the map. So, map.keySet() was not equal to loadAllKeys(). This caused the exception `MapLoader loaded an item belongs to a different partition`.

To solve this, I made sure that the output of map.keySet() is equal to loadAllKeys()

Comment: Can you elaborate your solution?